# ios splitviewcontroller landscape fail

Tags: ios, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have spliteview project and forced it in landscape mode. 
It works fine before I upgrade my iOS SDK to iOS6. 
But after upgrade, when I use iOS 5.1 Simulator to run, it always show in portrait mode and Master view is gone.

and here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

    CustomverDetailViewController *custView = [[[CustomverDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomverDetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, custView];


    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

### Any ideas?

I try to give different code for different version, in iOS6 it seems ok, but in iOS5.1 still will changing orientation while I enter this view, I guess when I alloc an new UIWindow , it orginial orientation is portrait.

here I changed my code:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

left = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:left] autorelease];


right = [[CustomverDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomverDetailViewController" bundle:nil];


self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, right];


if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue ] < 6.0 )) {


    self.splitViewController.delegate = left;
    [self.splitViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


}else{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

[right release];
```

[image: in iOS 6]
[image: in iOS 5.1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new delegate method added in iOS 6

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (void)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```